# emulator can't connect to Google App Engine dev server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-emulator, wsgi

In my Android emulator, I was able to contact the GAE dev server. 
I use this url: "http://10.0.2.2:8080/myurl".
The server is listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080.

Then, after I've updated the emulator to the Nexus 5X version with Google Play(API 27), the connection fails and the server show this log:

> ERROR    2018-01-11 11:17:05,463 wsgi_server.py:329] Request Host 10.0.2.2 not whitelisted. Enabled hosts are set(['127.0.0.1'])

I'm using the latest GAE python SDK with webapp2.

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: did you enable google play service in your emulator?

Comment: Since I use also Firebase, the app check the Play Service updates at every ap startup. It should be enabled and updated.

Answer (score 10):

The more recent versions of the development server includes whitelisting checks of the source IP address of incoming requests.

You can use the `--enable_host_checking=False` command line option for the GAE devserver, which disables these checks. Not a good idea if you're running on an untrusted network.

You're probably seeing such errors even for accessing the devserver from the same machine. Another option for these requests would be to use the `--host 10.0.2.2` devserver option (i.e. use your machine's external IP address instead of `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`, but that won't help with the emulator requests if you're running the emulator on some other machine.

Ideally the whitelist should IMHO be manageable independently from the server's IP address, but this is what is available presently.

Comment: Hi, could you include the full command to launch the development server with that parameter? 
I'm following this guide https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java and I don't find where to configure that. Thanks

Comment: @juanmeanwhile In that guide the server is driven by the maven plugin. I see it supports at least *some* development server options configurations: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven#specifying_a_port_for_local_testing. But I'm not a java user, I don't know if it's possible/how to configure the plugin for the whitelisting option.

Comment: @juanmeanwhile I'm not even sure if the java devserver itself supports whitelisting option, it doesn't appear listed in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server#command-line-arguments